# OpenCV parallel lines cull

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, image-recognition, object-detection

I have an algorithm that simply goes through a number of corners and finds those which are parallel. My problem is, as shown below, that I sometimes get false positive results.

To eliminate this I was going to check if both points fell onto a single hough line but this would be quite computationally intensive and I was wondering if anyone had any simpler ideas.

Thanks.

[image: False Positive Parallel Line]

Comment: By corners being parallel, are you referring to the corner direction? Because lines can be parallel, but not points.

Comment: Yes yes of course. I create a line between every point and then check if any of these lines are parallel to others and create parallel line pairs. The problem is I am getting false positives when I create lines from points where there is no line connecting them, as shown above. Beneath the brown lines there are no lines in the image connecting points.

Comment: To check if I've understood right... Are the grey lines already present in the image? And you're trying to find pairs of parallel grey lines?

Comment: The grey lines represent the image, yes. I have isolated this to search the points 4-7 and 1-8 to show the problem. The issue isn't with detecting parallel lines - that works, the issue is that it creates lines where there are no lines on the image, which is something I need to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok based on the comments, this should be fix-able. When you detect a pair of parallel lines, get the equation of the line using the two corners that you've used to construct it. This line may be of the form `y = mx + c`. Then for every `y` coordinate between the two points, compute the `x` coordinate. This gives you a set of all the pixels that the line segment covers. Go through these pixels, and check if the intensity at every pixel is closer to black than white. If a majority of the pixels in the set are black-ish, then it's a line. If not, it's probably a non-line.

Comment: That is essentially what I meant when I said I would compare it to the hough lines that I have collected. The problem is that this would be very CPU intensive and I was wondering if there might be an alternate solution to this.

Comment: You won't need to do a hough transform throughout the image. Just get the line equation starting with a pair of corners, and then traverse those pixels along the line. For an HD image with up to 200 corners or so, you should be able to get this done within 10ms.